# Having trouble adding paths

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, bezier-curves, path

I'm creating my first blender project and I'm trying to have the animated character follow a path. When I add the path in, there are no control points to make the path longer or  curved. I've googled it and haven't found any answers. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you try selecting the curve and going into edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

when in edit mode ( tab ) , press c this gives you a control circle that size you can control with mouse wheel, then press left mouse button on top of a verticle in the end of the path, then press g and ( grap ) and move the mouse to drag the path .

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> button while the path is selected, in order to enter Edit Mode, when done editing, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> again will bring the path back to Object Mode.
Hope this helps someone else